# How would I use the Field Validation module with Addressfield to make just city and province/state required?

Tags: entities

I have set my addressfeild to be completely optional, however, I want to use the field validation module to ensure they at least fill out city and province/state.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your node type field administration page, click the **validate** for your address field. Click the **Required field** validator link. On the validator form you want to:

1. Add your arbitrary **Rule name** (e.g. Address State)
2. In Column, select *locality* or *administrative_area* for City & State respectively.
3. Add your custom error message in the **Custom error message** field.
4. Click **Add rule** to add the validator.

Once added for both city/state this will force the address field's city/state to be entered.

Comment: I see where I went wrong in the first place-I needed to enable Field Validation Extras module. I have followed your steps and it still allows the form to be submitted. I even tried changing the settings to "Set errors using field API" just in case the addressfield module does something fancy in vaidation as it is a compund field.

Comment: Hmm, I tested with a vanilla D7 standard install with the latest version of Addressfield/Field Validation with no problems. The only other thing I can think of is cache issues or some module that might be overriding your node validation functions.